# Convert NA into a factor level

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a vector with `NA` values that I would like to replace by a new factor level `NA`.

```
a = as.factor(as.character(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, NA)))
a
[1] 1    1    2    2    3    <NA>
Levels: 1 2 3
```

This works, but it seems like a strange way to do it.

```
a = as.factor(ifelse(is.na(a), "NA", a))
class(a)
[1] "factor"
```

This is the expected output:

```
a
[1] 1  1  2  2  3  NA
Levels: 1 2 3 NA
```

Comment: Do you want to keep a `NA` or a `"NA"` in the levels and in the vector? Perhaps, instead of `as.character` you might have wanted `paste`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `addNA()`.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, NA)
addNA(x)
# [1] 1    1    2    2    3    <NA>
# Levels: 1 2 3 <NA>
```

This is basically a convenience function for factoring with `exclude = NULL`. From `help(factor)` -

> `addNA` modifies a factor by turning `NA` into an extra level (so that `NA` values are counted in tables, for instance).

So another reason this is nice is because if you already have a factor `f`, you can use `addNA()` to quickly add `NA` as a factor level without changing `f`.  As mentioned in the documentation, this is handy for tables.  It also reads nicely.

Comment: I used addNA. How can I get it in strings as the other levels? Cause my levels look like this "1" "2" "3" NA and i want it to be "1" "2" "3" "NA"

Answer (score 27):

You can add the NA as a level and change the level name to something more explicit than `<NA>` using `fct_explicit_na` from package *forcats*.

```
library(forcats)
```

By default you get the new level as `(Missing)`:

```
fct_explicit_na(a)

[1] 1         1         2         2         3         (Missing)
Levels: 1 2 3 (Missing)
```

You can set it to something else:

```
fct_explicit_na(a, "unknown")

[1] 1       1       2       2       3       unknown
Levels: 1 2 3 unknown
```

Comment: This function is now superseded and one should use `fct_na_value_to_level` instead (from `forcats 1.0.0`)

Answer (score 22):

Set the exclude argument to NULL to include NAs as levels (and use factor instead of as.factor. Does the same thing and has more arguments to set):

```
a = factor(as.character(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, NA)), exclude = NULL)

> a
[1] 1    1    2    2    3    <NA>
Levels: 1 2 3 <NA>
```

Comment: That's the better option when you want to order factor levels for plotting with `ggplot` :)